# How can I share code between multiple activities in Android?

Tags: android, function, android-activity

I am looking to share code between **multiple activities in Android** studio. I have Googled quite a bit, but can only seem to find how to share code between projects, or how to share data between activities.

Reason I would like to do this is I have several `try {} catch` blocks, and if there is an error I would like to save that data in a `sqlite` database. I can put the same function in every activity and call it, but that seems really inefficient, and is a pain when I need to slightly modify how it inserts the data, etc.

I would be passing in two parameters, `activity` name and error, and expecting a success/fail flag back.

Any thoughts is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Make one common class and functions and call it from any activities

Comment: How about create a parent class and child will extends it?

Comment: make abstract Activity and put the function in it which have the common functionality & extend the that activity by your all activies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create one Common class in package names common as Below :

```
public class Common {
private static Dialog dialog = null;

/*
* A Common function to display toast.
* */
public static Void displayToast(Context context, String strToast) {
    Toast.makeText(context, strToast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return null;
}

/*
* A Common function to display Log.
* */
public static Void displayLog(String strTitle, String strText) {
    Log.d(strTitle, strText);
    return null;
}

/*
* A Common function to check internet connection.
* */
public static boolean isOnline(Context c) {
    try {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) c.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

/*
* A common function to check length for input.
* */
public static boolean isValidLength(String fName) {
    if (fName.trim().length() > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/*
* A common function to validate Email id.
* */
public static boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
    String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```

Now, Access those functions in any of your activities as below :

```
Common.displayToast(MainActivity.this, "Message");
if (Common.isOnline(MainActivity.this)) {
              //your code
            } else {
                //your code
            }
```

Same way call necessary functions.

Comment: Thanks so much this actually explains what is going on rather than vague comments!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `BaseActivityClass` and extends all activity with this base class.

Like :

```
class BaseActivity extends Activity
{
} 

class your Actvity extends BaseActivity
{}
```

Write your all code in base activity and use in each activity accordingly.